# APA 6: How to get rid of the comma before "and [last author]"?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing, apa6

I am using the document class APA 6 (`\documentclass[man,a4paper,floatsintext,donotrepeattitle]{apa6}`) and Biblatex (`\usepackage[style=apa,sortcites=true,sorting=nyt,backend=biber]{biblatex}`) to write my thesis. I adapted this to the German settings for APA 6 and it works quite well, but I can't get rid of the comma in these situations:

[image]

The highlighted section in yellow below is the one I don't want in the German citation version (for English APA6, it would be correct). Has anyone got an idea of how to get rid of these commas (in the text and in the bibliography)?

MWEB:

```
 \documentclass[man,a4paper,floatsintext,donotrepeattitle]{apa6}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa,sortcites=true,sorting=nyt,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{german}{german-apa}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{
   andothers = {{et\,al\adddot}},}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@article{varazzani_noradrenaline_2015,
    title = {Noradrenaline and Dopamine Neurons in the Reward/Effort Trade-Off: A Direct Electrophysiological Comparison in Behaving Monkeys},
    volume = {35},
    issn = {0270-6474, 1529-2401},
    shorttitle = {Noradrenaline and Dopamine Neurons in the Reward/Effort Trade-Off},
    pages = {7866--7877},
    number = {20},
    journaltitle = {Journal of Neuroscience},
    author = {Varazzani, C. and San-Galli, A. and Gilardeau, S. and Bouret, S.},
    date = {2015},
    langid = {english}
}



\end{filecontents}
\shorttitle{Gedächtnisleistung und Pupillenweitung}
\begin{document}
Text \parencite{varazzani_noradrenaline_2015}
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide a [MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography).

Comment: I reinforce David's request. But in the meantime, a guess. Does this answer help? https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/400528/105447

Comment: An [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864) is really required to properly diagnose what is going on here. But you might also want to check your versions of `biblatex`, Biber and `biblatex-apa`. I seem to remember there was a problem with an older version of `biblatex-apa` that would incorrectrly enable the Oxford comma (comma before and) for German even though that is not wanted. That was fixed by an update a while ago.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I edited my question and included an MWEB. I will have a look at the other tips as well.

Comment: Your MWE shows only '&'s for me? You probably want not only `\DeclareLanguageMapping{german}{german-apa}`, but also `\DeclareLanguageMapping{ngerman}{ngerman-apa}` (that does not help with the problem, however).

Comment: That is another problem- for some citations, I get "[author], and [author]" and for some I get "[author], & [author]" (as in the MWEB)

Comment: If I use `\textcite` instead of `\parencite` I get 'und' without a comma before it, but of course then only the year is in brackets and not the entire citation. Please write `\litsfiles` to the very first line of your document and show us the output you get in the `.log` file, at the very end there will be a list with all the files used and their versions.

Comment: These are the files that have "biblatex" in the names:
biblatex.sty 2016/05/14 v3.4 programmable bibliographies (PK/JW/AB)
apa.dbx 2016/05/13 v6.9 APA biblatex style data model
biblatex-dm.cfg
blx-compat.def 2016/05/14 v3.4 biblatex compatibility (PK/JW/AB)

Comment: biblatex.def 2016/05/14 v3.4 biblatex compatibility (PK/JW/AB)
standard.bbx 2016/05/14 v3.4 biblatex bibliography style (PK/JW/AB)
apa.bbx 2016/05/13 v6.9 APA biblatex references style
apa.cbx 2016/05/13 v6.9 APA biblatex citation style
biblatex.cfg
german.lbx 2016/05/14 v3.4 biblatex localization (PK/JW/AB)
german-apa.lbx 2016/05/13 v6.9 APA biblatex localisation
ngerman.lbx 2016/05/14 v3.4 biblatex localization (PK/JW/AB)

Comment: Your versions of `biblatex` and `biblatex-apa` as well as Biber are out of date. The current version of `biblatex` is 3.8a, that of Biber 2.8 and `biblatex-apa` is at 7.5. I'd suggest an update, but you need to be aware of the fact that updates could always cause trouble. How soon does the document need to be ready?

Comment: It has to be ready in 5 weeks and I would rather not change anything major until then.. Do you have an idea of how to address this problem without updating the packages?

Comment: do you want *und* or *&*? I can modify my answer to provide *und* everywhere.

Comment: I modified my answer to show how you can get *und* if you want it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comments, this is fixed for more recent versions of `biblatex-apa`, but it's not too hard to make things work without upgrading.

You need to redefine `\finalandcomma` for the `ngerman` language:

```
\DefineBibliographyExtras{ngerman}{
  \def\finalandcomma{}
}
```

Also, I notice you have `ngerman` as your `babel` language, but then you instruct `biblatex-apa` to use `german`. Shouldn't they be the same?

If you want *und* instead of *&*, then add this to the preamble of the MWE below:

```
\AtEveryCitekey{%
  \renewcommand{\finalnamedelim}{%
    \ifnum\value{liststop}>2 \finalandcomma\fi\addspace\bibstring{and}\space}}
\AtBeginBibliography{\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{%
    \ifthenelse{\value{listcount}>\maxprtauth}
      {}
      {\ifthenelse{\value{liststop}>2}
        {\finalandcomma\addspace\bibstring{and}\space}
         {\addspace\bibstring{and}\space}}}}
```

Here's my MWE. It works with your versions of `biblatex`, `biber`, and `biblatex-apa`. (It uses *&* instead of *und*, but I assume you've changed other things to deal with this, since *&* is hard coded in `biblatex-apa`.)

```
\documentclass[man,a4paper,floatsintext,donotrepeattitle]{apa6}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa,sortcites=true,sorting=nyt,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{ngerman}{ngerman-apa}% <-- use ngerman mapping
\usepackage{booktabs}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{
   andothers = {{et\,al\adddot}},}
\DefineBibliographyExtras{ngerman}{% <-- redefine finalandcomma for ngerman
  \def\finalandcomma{}
}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@article{varazzani_noradrenaline_2015,
    title = {Noradrenaline and Dopamine Neurons in the Reward/Effort Trade-Off: A Direct Electrophysiological Comparison in Behaving Monkeys},
    volume = {35},
    issn = {0270-6474, 1529-2401},
    shorttitle = {Noradrenaline and Dopamine Neurons in the Reward/Effort Trade-Off},
    pages = {7866--7877},
    number = {20},
    journaltitle = {Journal of Neuroscience},
    author = {Varazzani, C. and San-Galli, A. and Gilardeau, S. and Bouret, S.},
    date = {2015},
    langid = {english}
}
\end{filecontents}
\shorttitle{Gedächtnisleistung und Pupillenweitung}
\begin{document}
Text \parencite{varazzani_noradrenaline_2015}
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, this works perfectly. Also, I changed "german" to "ngerman" for all the settings. I looked up my citation manual, the "&" is correct for \parencite, the "und" for \textcite.