# Combination of polyglossia + biblatex + csquotes ignoring autopunct setting

Tags: biblatex, polyglossia, csquotes

I’m having trouble to get `biblatex` respect the `autopunct` option of the `csquotes` package when using `polyglossia`.
I want to print my references as

> I. N. Proceedings. “Title of the Work.” In: 2019.

not as

> I. N. Proceedings. “Title of the Work”. In: 2019.

(Note the placement of the `.` before `”`).

In the following MWE, this is achieved when I use Babel, but *not* when I use `polyglossia`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @inproceedings{example,
    author = {Proceedings, I. N.},
    year = {2019},
    title = {Title of the Work},
  }
\end{filecontents}

\newif\ifusepolyglossia
\usepolyglossiatrue
%\usepolyglossiafalse
\ifusepolyglossia
  \usepackage{polyglossia}
  \setdefaultlanguage[variant=usmax]{english}
\else
 \usepackage[american]{babel}
\fi
\usepackage[autopunct]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{example}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Am I doing something wrong, or did I just encounter a bug in one of these packages?
I compile my document using LuaLaTeX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the result of a incompatibility between `biblatex` and `polyglossia`'s language interface. With `polyglossia` `biblatex` can only detect the main language (`english` in this case) and not the language variant (`american`). Often this issue will go unnoticed, but it can cause some unwanted effects in certain edge cases like this. That is the reason why the next `version` of `biblatex` will issue a warning if it is used with `polyglossia` again: https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/845.

---

The full American punctuation scheme for quotation is only enabled when `biblatex` detects American English (`american`) and not with generic English (`english`), which is otherwise identical to American English. With `polyglossia` we only ever detect `english`, so the US punctuation scheme is not enabled. (Just to be clear: Moving of punctuation around quotation marks produced by `biblatex` in the bibliography is solely controlled by `biblatex` and its commands `\uspunctuation` and `\stdpunctuation`. `csquotes`' `autopunct` option has no say in this.)

The following line will enable US quotation-punctuation rules even with plain `english`

```
\DefineBibliographyExtras{english}{\uspunctuation}
```

Alternatively, you can map `english` to `american` with

```
\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{american}
```

but note that this is explicitly discouraged in the `biblatex` documentation. The advantage of this approach over the specific `\DefineBibliographyExtras{english}{\uspunctuation}` would be that it would automatically copy over *all* of `american`s settings to `english` and not just the `\uspunctuation`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newif\ifusepolyglossia
\usepolyglossiatrue
%\usepolyglossiafalse
\ifusepolyglossia
  \usepackage{polyglossia}
  \setdefaultlanguage[variant=usmax]{english}
\else
 \usepackage[american]{babel}
\fi
\usepackage[autopunct]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\DefineBibliographyExtras{english}{\uspunctuation}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Emma Sigfridsson and Ulf Ryde. “Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments.” In: Journal of Computational Chemistry 19.4 (1998), pp. 377–395. doi: 10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P.]

A related issue is discussed in [Biblatex-Chicago and non-US quotation style?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/400524/35864). [Localized date with biblatex and polyglossia](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/464281/35864), [\DeclareLanguageMappingSuffix, inheritance, and polyglossia in biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/432347/35864) and [How do we get Polyglossia language variants to work with Biblatex bibliographies?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/324849/35864) deal with the compatibility issues between `biblatex` and `polyglossia`.

---

A while ago I would have unequivocally recommended to abandon `polyglossia` for `babel` if at all possible, since `babel` is developed actively (again) and `polyglossia` largely seemed dormant. In practice `babel` works as well as (if not better than) `polyglossia` for most (Western) European languages, but `babel` also makes progress in areas where `polyglossia` was traditionally stronger (Hebrew, Arabic, ...). See [Decide between Polyglossia and Babel for LuaLaTeX in 2019](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/482396/35864). Very recently there has been some development on the [`polyglossia` GitHub page](https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia), so maybe the project is gaining momentum again. (As an aside I think that the LaTeX community would benefit if the two projects were merged in some shape or form instead of continue to be developed independently with a similar aim. The ups and downs of the development just confuse people about which package to take.)

Comment: Thank you a lot for your very clear and complete answer. I thought indeed that the `csquotes` macros would be used for this in `biblatex`, certainly because `biblatex` recommends to use `csquotes`!

Comment: @timothymctim When `csquotes` is loaded `biblatex` makes use of its facilities and quotations get a lot smarter than they are if only `biblatex`'s own implementations are used. But the punctuation moving stuff is quite complicated in general and the implementation in `csquotes` is very sensitive to context so that `biblatex` has to use its own way of moving punctuation marks.